# How do I false a user to enter two different phone numbers and show jQuery validation

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a form that I'm trying to validate by making the user enter two different phone numbers, i.e. Home and a mobile.

Form at moment allows the same number, which is not what I want.

I do have a third party script validating but with not much scripting to my name am not sure how to customise to my needs, any help would be great, thank you 
Form can be seen at, http://willettsbutchers.co.uk/onlineOrdering/onlineOrdering.php

This is the bit of script that validates the current phone fields,

```
"phone":{
    // credit: jquery.h5validate.js
"regex": /^([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-          \/]{8,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/,
"alertText":"* Invalid Phone Number" 
},
```

And this is the code that's in the body of the html,

```
<tr>
      <td><p class="phone_number">
          <label for="Phone">Home Phone Number <span class="starSymbol">*</span></label>
          <br>
          <input name="Phone" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[phone]] text-input" id="Phone" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Phone'])){print $_POST['Phone'];}else{print "";} ?>"/>
        </p>
    <p class="phone_number"></p></td>
      <td><p class="mobile">
          <label for="Mobile">Mobile Phone Number <span class="starSymbol">*</span></label>
          <br>
          <input name="Mobile" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[phone]] text-input" id="Mobile" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['Mobile'])){print $_POST['Mobile'];}else{print "";} ?>"/>
        </p>
    <p class="mobile"></p></td>
    </tr>
<tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick little example

```
<input id="homPhone" class="phoneinput" placeholder="Home phone"/><br><br>
<input id="mobPhone" class="phoneinput" placeholder="Mobile phone"/><span class="phoneerror"></span>

$(".phoneinput").change(function() {
    if($("#homPhone").val() == $("#mobPhone").val()) {
        $(".phoneerror").text("They're the same!");
    } else {
        $(".phoneerror").text("");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/link2twenty/j3rxu0vx/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a custom method, something like this:

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("notEqual", function(value, element, param) {
   return this.optional(element) || value != $(param).val();
}, "Please provide other than Home phone number");
```

Then use it like this:

```
$("form").validate({
  rules: {
    MobilePhone: { notEqual: "#HomePhone" }
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, my scripting is very limited, sorry. not too sure where to put the code, and I would like the error messages to show as is no the form at present.

Comment: So not having much luck I have the following list of code which, through the JS validate the fields, just want to add the the current code to stop the same entry being added.The line "phone":{
    // credit: jquery.h5validate.js
"regex": /^([\+][0-9]{1,3}[ \.\-])?([\(]{1}[0-9]{2,6}[\)])?([0-9 \.\-          \/]{8,20})((x|ext|extension)[ ]?[0-9]{1,4})?$/,
"alertText":"* Invalid Phone Number" 
}, runs the validation just need to add a bit of code that solves the issue?

Comment: This Fixed the issue,  For the mobile field if you change the class to validate[required,custom[phone],funcCall[checkPhone]] and added to below to the head section of page,

function checkPhone(field, rules, i, options){
 if (field.val() == $('#Phone').val()) {
    // this allows the use of i18 for the error msgs
    return 'Phone and mobile can not be the same';
 }
}